# If $f^{n}$ is holomorphic, then f is also holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis

Could you help me please on how to demonstrate this problem.

If $f^{n}$ is holomorphic, then f is also holomorphic.

Comment: Is $f^n$ a derivative, a power, or functional composition? Also what have you tried?

Comment: logically, it can be the power only ! (but indeed, at the beginning I thought it was the derivative, but it doesn't make sense since the statement would be obvious. For the composition, it's for linear application only that the notation $f^n$ is used @frogeyedpeas

Comment: $f(z)=\sqrt z$ (some branch) and $n=2$ is a counterexample. If $f$ is continuous then the assertion is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need continuity of $f$. Otherwise this is false. I suppose by $f^{n}$ you mean the n-th power. Use definition of differentability. We have $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f^{n}(z+h)-f^{n}(z)} h \to $ a finite limit $L$. Using the identity $a^{n}-b^{n}=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+ab^{n-1}+b^{n-1})$ conclude that $f$ is differentiable at $z$ if $f(z) \neq 0$. Now the zeros of $f^{n}$ (which are same as zeros of $f$) are isolated. Around these isolated points $f$ is bounded and hence it singularity is removable.

Answer (score 1):

Every individual branch of the $n$-th root (which is a multi-valied function in the complex plane) is holomorphic.  $f$ is the composition of $f^{n}$ and of such a branch in an appropriate domain (a branch is holomorphic in a subset of the complex plane); i.e., is a composition of two holomoprhic functions in that domain.

(See, e.g., page 57 in [Cartan's book on complex analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=SlpwANmq5xQC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=many-valued&f=false).)

Comment: If you interpret $f^{n}$ as n-th iteration of $f$ then  the result is false without continuity assumption. A simple counterexample is $f(z)=\frac 1 z$ fro $z \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, edited accordingly.  (BTW, the question doesn't specify whether we are talking about holomoprhy in a proper subset of the complex plane, or of functions which are *entire*.)